# Coordinates of boxes in Seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), extended [here](http://composition.al/blog/2015/11/29/a-better-way-to-add-labels-to-bar-charts-with-matplotlib/), shows how to label bar plots in Matplotlib; a similar idea can be used to label box plots.  It relies on knowing the x and y coordinates of the bars, which are returned by the barplot function.  How can I do the same thing for [Seaborn box plots](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)?  Unfortunately Seaborn does not return these coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hack around a bit to find them, but its not pretty.

`sns.boxplot` returns the `matplotlib` Axes instance the boxes are drawn on.

The boxes are created as `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` instances.

We can find those instances like so:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

for c in ax.get_children():
    if type(c) == matplotlib.patches.PathPatch:
        print(c.get_extents())
```

This will print the `BBox` of the boxes, in this example:

```
Bbox(x0=92.4, y0=116.996, x1=191.6, y1=162.242666667)
Bbox(x0=216.4, y0=114.957333333, x1=315.6, y1=171.6)
Bbox(x0=340.4, y0=125.576, x1=439.6, y1=189.141333333)
Bbox(x0=464.4, y0=131.926666667, x1=563.6, y1=194.172)
```

Comment: Hmm, any idea how to find how their coordinates system works?